Force on charged particles by light
Light is an em wave and by definition I know that em wave is oscillating electric and magnetic field. So  Why doesn't light apply force on charged particles as it has both electric and magnetic field?

What is the question?

The question is if light is em wave (oscillating electric and magnetic field) then it should apply force on charged particles

That is still not a question, it is a statement. A question ends with a question mark.

Does this answer your question? What is the magnitude of the force on a charged particle due to electromagnetic radiation?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Edited the OP to make it a question.

Let me ask it in a different way

Suppose in empty space there is light coming from a source and if I put a charged particle in the path of light. Will the charge particle experience some force?

Please do not ask the same question twice. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/813558/174766

Is it a hard question or dumb question because nobody is answering

"So Why doesn't light apply force on charged particles..." It does. Why are you implying that it doesn't? Are you asking us, or did you just come here to assert the wrong answer in your question?

I am asking this because I have not studied about a single phenomena which is based on the principle of force on charged particles by visible light. If anyone knows some phenomena based on this principle please write about it.

Does this answer your question? Force on charge particle by light

The force is $\mathbf F=q(\mathbf E+\mathbf v\times\mathbf B)$.

This is the formula of Lorentz force

Yes, and it applies here since light is nothing more than $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields. Why did you think it didn’t apply?

Because I didn't studied about a single phenomena based on this principle

Why did you post the same question twice? This violates the site’s rules and probably explains some of the downvotes.

Because I didn't studied about a single phenomena based on this principle. You’re only in high school. If you continue to study physics you will learn about many interesting phenomena related to the interaction between electromagnetic waves and charged particles.

EM radiation applies a force to charged particles. See:
Index of refraction.
Antenna (esp. Rx side).
Plasma cutoff frequency.
Compton scattering.
Bremsstrahlung (literally: braking radiation.)

I am in High school so I didn't know about the effects you mentioned above . If I put a charged particle with very less mass in path of visible light not any other em wave will it experience a force or not.

@HimanshuNirwam YES it will experience a force: $F=q(\vec E +\vec v\times\vec B)$

@HimanshuNirwam note that "visible light" isn't a thing until you pick the charged particle's velocity. An abstract plane wave or photon out in deep space can have any frequency you want it to. If I fire the charged particle out of accelerator opposite the light, now that visible light is a gamma ray. Turn the accelerator around, and now it's a microwave.
